# jquery background change

Tags: jquery, css, background

Consider the following situation. I've 2 types of backgrounds: 1.Photoshop gradients for which I use CSS markup like:

```
html{
                background-image: url('imgs/gradient.png');
                background-repeat: repeat-x;
                background-color: #000000;
            }
```

2.Background patterns for which the markup is as follows

```
html{
    background-image:url('paper.gif');
}
```

The following Jquery is responsible for the background change:

```
$(function() {
            $('a').click(function() {
                var currentLink = $(this);
                var which = $(this).attr('id');
                //Color scheme variables(image,color)
                var image = '';
                var color = '';
      //gradient + color background
                if (which == 'a1')
                    {image = "url(backgrounds/pat2.png)";
                    color = "#3a2c33";}
     //pattern type background
                       else if(which == 'a2')
                    {image = "url(backgrounds/pat4.jpg)";
                    color = " ";}
                if(color != " "){
                    $('html').css("background-image", image);
                    $('html').css("background-color", color);
                }
                else{
                    $('html').css("background", image);
                }
            return false;
            });
        });
```

If I select pattern type background and then gradient/color type background the background color couldn't be initialised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need to clear the background attribute since it may be leaving both background, background-image, and background-color all at once?

Answer (score 2):

Rather than juggle `background` CSS values in JS, you should use a class on `html` and toggle that.

```
html { background-image:url('paper.gif'); }
html.alt { background:#000 url('imgs/gradient.png') repeat-x; }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that the background style should be on `body` and not on the `html`